# return id on mysql create if not exists query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table:

```
CREATE TABLE `table_listnames` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
`name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`address` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`tele` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

and a query:

```
INSERT INTO table_listnames (name, address, tele)
SELECT * FROM (SELECT 'Rupert', 'Somewhere', '022') AS tmp
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
SELECT name FROM table_listnames WHERE name = 'Rupert'
) LIMIT 1;
```

I would like the query to print out the id of the record that was inserted or or was selected.  Any ideas?  Thanks!

Comment: SELECT TOP 1 id FROM table_listnames
ORDER BY id DESC

Answer (score 1):

You can get the last inserted autoincrement value with LAST_INSERTED_ID, see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id.

It's a good idea to check the number of the affected rows first. You can successfully execute your query with no matching row.

Answer (score 0):

Well, basically to get the id of the record that was inserted:

Run another query just after that by, `SELECT id FROM table_listnames WHERE name = ''`

Basically, your code will have the records in a variable while inserting, so use the $name variable to select the ID, and `$result = mysql_query($query);` To store the result in the $result variable.

To get the ID of the record that was selected, basically:

```
SELECT id FROM table_listnames WHERE something = 'something'
```

So lets, say your PHP code selected the name field with a $name variable storing the data to match, you can just add `SELECT id`, and you can store that result to variable like, `$result = mysql_query($query);` Where $query holds the SQL you are running.

I hope this is what you expected. Eventhough I used mysql_* functions to explain you, please do not use mysql_* functions.